# Missing libraries while installing MySQL on RHEL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to instlal mysql on RHEL and followed below steps :

1. sudo yum localinstall https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el7-9.noarch.rpm
2. sudo yum install mysql-community-server
3. Then , I encounter the

   Error: Package: 2:postfix-2.10.1-9.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda/7.8)
   Requires: libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)
   Removing: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.68-1.el7.x86_64 (@rhel-7-server-rpms)
   libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)
   Obsoleted By: mysql-community-libs-5.7.38-1.el6.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
   ~libmysqlclient.so.20()(64bit)
   Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
   libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)
   Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.37-1.el7_0.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
   libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)
   Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.40-1.el7_0.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
   libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)
   Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.40-2.el7_0.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
   libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)
   Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.41-2.el7_0.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
   libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)
   Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
   libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)
   Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.44-2.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
   libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)
   Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.47-1.el7_2.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
   libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)
   Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.50-1.el7_2.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
   libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)
   Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
   libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)
   Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.56-2.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
   libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)
   Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.60-1.el7_5.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
   libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)
   Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.64-1.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
   libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)
   Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.65-1.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
   libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)
   You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6p8Yu.png)

Appreciate any replies or feedback. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I was installing MySQL5.7.31 from mysql-5.7.31-1.el7.x86_64.rpm-bundle.tar, I had the similar problem. I was using CentOS then.Try the following steps:(Note:Some of them are redundant, which can be skipped. But I haven't got round to the testing.) 
1.Uninstall mariadb libs:

```
yum remove mariadb-libs
```

2.Install perl dependencies:

```
yum localinstall perl-5.16.3-295.el7.x86_64.rpm
yum localinstall perl-Carp-1.26-244.el7.noarch.rpm
yum localinstall perl-constant-1.27-2.el7.noarch.rpm
yum localinstall perl-Encode-2.51-7.el7.x86_64.rpm
yum localinstall perl-Exporter-5.68-3.el7.noarch.rpm
yum localinstall perl-File-Path-2.09-2.el7.noarch.rpm
yum localinstall perl-File-Temp-0.23.01-3.el7.noarch.rpm
yum localinstall perl-Filter-1.49-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
yum localinstall perl-Getopt-Long-2.40-3.el7.noarch.rpm
yum localinstall perl-HTTP-Tiny-0.033-3.el7.noarch.rpm
yum localinstall perl-libs-5.16.3-295.el7.x86_64.rpm
yum localinstall perl-macros-5.16.3-295.el7.x86_64.rpm
yum localinstall perl-parent-0.225-244.el7.noarch.rpm
yum localinstall perl-PathTools-3.40-5.el7.x86_64.rpm
yum localinstall perl-Pod-Escapes-1.04-295.el7.noarch.rpm
yum localinstall perl-podlators-2.5.1-3.el7.noarch.rpm
yum localinstall perl-Pod-Perldoc-3.20-4.el7.noarch.rpm
yum localinstall perl-Pod-Simple-3.28-4.el7.noarch.rpm
yum localinstall perl-Pod-Usage-1.63-3.el7.noarch.rpm
yum localinstall perl-Scalar-List-Utils-1.27-248.el7.x86_64.rpm
yum localinstall perl-Socket-2.010-5.el7.x86_64.rpm
yum localinstall perl-Storable-2.45-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
yum localinstall perl-Text-ParseWords-3.29-4.el7.noarch.rpm
yum localinstall perl-threads-1.87-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
yum localinstall perl-threads-shared-1.43-6.el7.x86_64.rpm
yum localinstall perl-Time-HiRes-1.9725-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
yum localinstall perl-Time-Local-1.2300-2.el7.noarch.rpm
```

3.Install other prerequisites:

```
yum localinstall mysql-community-common-5.7.31-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
yum localinstall mysql-community-libs-5.7.31-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
yum localinstall mysql-community-client-5.7.31-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
yum localinstall mysql-community-server-5.7.31-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch and just my removing/cleaning up the maria-db libs , has done the trick for me. Appreciate your time . Thanks you once again.

Comment: My pleasure. It is actually just a copy & paste job for me as I like recording my experiments on a notepad. : )